# apply permission to child folders while keeping existing permissions

Tags: windows, permissions

I have lots of levels of nested folders and I need to make changes so that existing permissions are kept.

As an example I have a folder david with david1 inside it and david2 inside this.

If I give access to a user on david2 and then I go to root level david and I add permissions for a new user and go to advanced and propagate changes down to child users all the existing changes are gone for example that user I added with permission to david2.

Is there any way around making a change so that the existing permissions are kept? Perhaops this can be done with powershell?

Comment: get/set-acl https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849810.aspx

Answer (score -1):

That shouldn't happen. In the child folder (David2), under Security -> Advanced, do you have "Include Inheritable Permissions" checked off? They should "merge" together. I just tested this out as a sanity check and it works as I thought. What does it say in the "Effective Permissions" tab when you change permissions in the parent folder?

Comment: That should *exactly* happen. You missed the bit where he said he ticked the 'Replace all child object permissions' box.

Comment: I wanted to add this as a comment, but didn't have enough rep. Don't see why it would edit child ACL's to explicitly match the parent. That makes no sense on any OS. It should inherit and merge.

Comment: The option clearly states "**Replace all** child permissions". I don't see where the ambiguity is in "Replace all". There's even a pop-up box that asks you to confirm: "This will **replace** explicitly defined permissions on all descendants". Leaving inconsistent and messy permissions all over the place when you explicitly tell it to replace them makes no sense on any OS. It should never merge when you explicitly tell it to remove.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Is there a seperate option I could be using to merge these settings or am just not able to do this? Perhaps should I be looking at PowerShell commands or will this help me either?

Comment: @daithi_dearg: No, there's no easy alternative. Windows ACLs are meant to work in an inherit-or-replace fashion. You'll have to use PowerShell to merge without replacing. I don't know the exact command but you can manually turn on inheritance on each child which will then add anything you apply to the parent folder without deleting the child's own permissions.

Comment: The question must be missing some info, as I've read it twice now. Why does inheriting not work in this situation??? Does the user require fewer permission on the child object? Then use a deny rule. Otherwise, inheriting is your solution. Can you be more specific in your question @daithi_dearg ?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq, Do a Ctrl+F and find me one hit where he says "Replace all child permissions". Which question are you even reading?

Comment: @Ryan: Perhaps you should try reading what he said again... "I add permissions for a new user and go to advanced and propagate changes down to child users". Now, go to advanced, and find any "Propagate" checkbox that does not say "Replace all" at the beginning it. Perhaps you need the OP to spell out verbatim every sequence of mouse clicks but the rest of us can figure out what option he was referring to when he does not state the option verbatim letter for letter.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq I can click allow inheritable positions and it works for some of the nested folders but not for others. Is there anything I can check as to why some folders are inheriting and others aren't? I can't see where powershell will offer any assistance as I'd still have to check permissions for each and every parent.